# What factors should I consider to prepare high protein meals using a single camping stove and pan?

Tags: food, nutrition

I understand the basics of trek / hiking meals which are primarily freeze-dried, lightweight and carbohydrate rich.

For those of us with access to a base camp who wish to consume mainly protein supplemented with fats what are you recommendations for protein or fat rich foods using traditional camping methods (Stove, Gas, JetBoil etc).  A large part of the outdoor diet is comprised of freeze dried and carbohydrate rich / high sodium ingredients.

What factors should I consider to prepare high protein meals using a single camping stove and pan?

- Ease of transport
- Items that don't require refrigeration
- Items which can be cooked without the use of a campfire, microwave, oven or slow cooker type device

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52456/discussion-on-question-by-venture2099-what-factors-should-i-consider-to-prepare). Yes, this question is on topic. No - discussion about particular ideas of high protein is not on topic...do that in the chat.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I am pretty certain that this is what you are looking for,

[image: jar of peanut butter]

[Image Source](https://www.myamericanmarket.com/us/jif-peanut-butter-extra-crunchy)

Two tablespoons (32g) of the stuff has **8g of protein** and **16g of fat**.

[Source](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=protein%20in%20peanut%20butter)

It easy to carry, does not require refrigeration or cooking. Typically I eat it straight out of the jar with a spoon and **can go through one of the jars pictured in about a week.**  Yes, it does get old after a while.

For more ideas take a look at this [list](http://blackwoodspress.com/blog/21416/high-protein-hiking-foods/) which includes;

- Jerky
- Foil wrapped fish and meat
- Cured bacon and sausage
- Freeze dried meat
- Cheeses
- Powdered milk
- Protein powders
- Protein bars
- Nut butters
- Legumes
- Nuts
- Seeds

In addition the list can be expanded with

- Powdered egg whites
- Freeze dried yohgurt
- Lentils
- Homemade protein bread from coconut flour, eggs, coconut milk

Comment: Awesome and made me smile.  The list is great thank you.

Comment: that was my first thought as well when I read the question. "protein and fat". hum, sounds like peanut butter! (although I am partial to crunchy myself.)

Comment: I realize that the picture of the peanut butter jar was meant to lighten things up, but the calories in peanut butter are 72% from fat, 12% from carbs, and 16% from protein. So it's a really awesome source of calories, and specifically of fat, but if we suppose for the moment that the goal is to boost protein, it's not going to work so well. Of course the OP did ask about boosting both fat and protein, but anyway, just sayin'.

Comment: @BenCrowell It you look at the list peanut butter has a ratio of 7 grams/ounce which is pretty good. There are things with higher ratios, but they all cost more. Going by weight its 50% fat and 25% protein.

Comment: @CharlieBrumbaugh: What you say is true, but when a food has that much fat content, it's going to be very satiating, and that means that it's going to be hard to eat enough of it to get a ton of protein. Similar issue with whole eggs.

Comment: @BenCrowell I ran some numbers, and if the reccomend protein per day is 56 grams that works out to about 1/2 lb of peanut butter or 1/5 of the jar pictured. Having eaten that much in a day before it is doable, but not particularly tasty.

Comment: I especially liked the fish in foil tip. I don't fish much at home but I always bring a pole when I go backpacking. Fresh fish is tasty, nutritious, and a great addition to freeze dried dinners. The best part is that the fish weighs more than the pole and tackle so it is like carrying negative weight. ;)

Comment: Don't encourage people to take glass jars or bottles camping as they are heavy and get thrown on the trail.

Comment: @QuentinUK Peanut butter comes in plastic jars, at least where I am at.

Comment: @CharieBrumbaugh In the UK it is usually sold in glass jars. There is one brand, SunPat, that has recently started to be sold in a plastic jar but it is an odd curvy shape that prevents one getting all the butter out of it.

Answer (score 12):

> what are you recommendations for protein or fat rich foods using traditional camping methods

Focusing on the fat part, the following are all practical sources:

- olive oil, or any other vegetable oil, which you can add to rice or pasta, dip crackers in etc.
- nuts
- ghee
- hard cheeses
- string cheese (if you can find some that's not nonfat)
- salami, pepperoni, slim jims, etc.

You can also increase fat by substituting crackers and potato chips for bread and tortillas. Potato chips can be put through a food processor to make them more compact.

For a long trip where you're worried about energy debt and undesired weight loss, it makes sense to find palatable ways to add fat to your food supply, because it's the most dense form of food energy, at 9 kcals/gram. Since the question seems to be motivated by a desire to reduce carbs, I will just note that carbs serve as the primer for fat metabolism, and if you don't have enough carbs in proportion to fat, you will get incomplete fat metabolism, which leads to accumulation of ketone bodies.

Comment: Thanks for the tip regarding ketone bodies.  I have marked the other answer for completeness but this was really useful too.

Comment: Scott would drink cocoa made with butter instead of water.