# How to make peanut butter less sticky?

Tags: food

Peanut butter can be good [source of protein](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/14999/8794) or useful for [emergency rations](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/18224/8794), but it can be sticky and not finger friendly, how can you make it less sticky?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The trick is to mix it with something else such as,

- Powdered Milk
- Oatmeal
- Powdered sugar
- Graham Crackers
- Rice Crispies

You can also add other things to increase the sweetness like,

- Chocolate Chips
- Honey

What you are looking for is for the combination to have the consistency of Play-Doh. What you can do then is wrap the ball in saran wrap to keep it together. This has the advantage of not having it in the plastic container, which doesn't shrink as the peanut butter is eaten.

If you are looking for exact recipes, the thing you are looking for is "No-bake Peanut Butter Balls"

Comment: If you want to save some plastic wrap and don't need it portioned into balls, you can wrap it in a log shape and squeeze out as needed (a la toothpaste).